# layout_alignParentRight not working for relative layout inside linear layout

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I have two relative layout inside linear layout. I want the first relative layout left align and the second relative layout right align. I set the following line in the second relative layout but it is not working.

```
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
```

and my full xml file goes here.

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:weightSum="100">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/left"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="45"
        android:background="@drawable/listview">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/leftPanelImage"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:src="@drawable/sports"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="left panel"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/leftPanelImage"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="45"
        android:background="@drawable/listview"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        >
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/rightPanelImage"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:src="@drawable/sports"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="right panel"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/rightPanelImage"/>
    </RelativeLayout>



</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

My current code gives an output like this. Second layout start after first layout. I want it to start from the right from parent.

[image]

So my question is how can I set the second relative layout right align.

Thank you.

Comment: LinearLayouts don't use **relativity**. `layout_alignParentRight` can work if you put a LinearLayout `inside a RelativeLayout`, not the opposite.

Comment: I set the layout_weight to fit it in different screen size.

Comment: Can you please guide me how to use layout_weight in relative layout?

Comment: @DerGolem Thank you for your correction,I'll keep it in mind. :-]

Answer (score 3):

android:layout_alignParentRight is for children within relative layout. Since your relative layouts are children for linear layout, try using

```
android:layout_gravity="left"
```

and

```
android:layout_gravity="right"
```

Answer (score 1):

Your layout seems to be very overkill, using `LinearLayout` weights and `RelativeLayout` for such a simple layout is not necesseary. Also both these methods requiere double measurement which is slower. I would suggest to always use as few elements as possible – for your layout try something like

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    ...
    android:weightSum="100">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="45"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/sports"
        android:drawablePadding="5dp"
        android:text="left panel"/>

    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="10"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="45"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/listview"
        android:drawablePadding="5dp"
        android:text="right panel"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

`android:layout_alignParentRight` and `android:layout_alignParentLeft` are used to align a child right or left inside a relative layout. Of course, it won't work with LinearLayout as parent. You can change your parent layout to RelativeLayout.

Comment: Thank you I got it. But if I change the parent layout to relative layout, the layout_weight won't work

Comment: How about instead of android:layout_alignParentRight and android:layout_alignParentLeft, use android:layout_gravity = "right" and android:layout_gravity="left" and still keep the layout_weight?

Comment: Well, in that case you can use the trick: Place a View (with no content) in between 2 RelativeLayouts and set its layout_weight to be 10 (100 - 45 -45).

Answer (score 0):

**android:layout_alignParentRight** attribute is meant to work in children of Relative Layouts. You are using in in a child of a Linear Layout.

You can set it to the childs of the RelativeLayout OR use on the parent view android:gravity="right".

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="45"
        android:background="@drawable/listview">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/rightPanelImage"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:src="@drawable/sports"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="right panel"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/rightPanelImage"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Is there any way to use percentage in relative layout?

Comment: Can you try android:gravity="right" before consider the use of RelativeLayouts?